# How do I create an executable in Visual Studio 2013 w/ C++?

Tags: c++, exe, visual-studio-2013

I can't find the exe file for my Hello World program that succeeded to work, and the program did not open as soon as it said it worked. I tried going to my documents and checking my project's folder.  It was completely empty.  Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Look for a folder named `Debug` or `Release`, it should be in there.

Comment: From the command prompt, cd to the root of your project directory. Then type `dir /s *.exe`

Comment: Perhaps run the debug option from the menu?

Comment: Edit: I was looking in the wrong folder, sorry.

Answer (score 12):

All executable files from Visual Studio should be located in the debug folder of your project, e.g:

> Visual Studio Directory: c:\users\me\documents\visual studio

Then the project which was called 'hello world' would be in the directory:

> c:\users\me\documents\visual studio\hello world

And your exe would be located in:

> c:\users\me\documents\visual studio\hello world\Debug\hello world.exe

Note the exe being named the same as the project.

Otherwise, you could publish it to a specified folder of your choice which comes with an installation, which would be good if you wanted to distribute it quickly

**EDIT:**

Everytime you build your project in VS, the exe is updated with the new one according to the code (as long as it builds without errors). When you publish it, you can choose the location, aswell as other factors, and the setup exe will be in that location, aswell as some manifest files and other files about the project.

Comment: Would the release version of the executables be in the debug folder of the project (as your answer states)?

Comment: 64-bit applications are compiled to `hello world\x64\<Configuration>\hello world.exe`. Those are the predefined locations that can be adjusted at will, either through the GUI or by edition the *.vcproj file directly.

Answer (score 5):

1. Click BUILD > Configuration Manager...
2. Under Project contexts > Configuration, select "Release"
3. BUILD > Build Solution or Rebuild Solution

Answer (score 2):

Just click on "Build" on the top menu and then click on "Publish ".... Then a pop up will open and there u can define the folder which u want to save the .exe file and by clicking "Next" will allow u to set up the advanced settings...
DONE!

Comment: Nope! The BUILD menu doesn't have such an "Publish" item for a C++ project.

Comment: How would you change your program name upon publishing ?

Answer (score 1):

Do ctrl+F5 to compile and run your project without debugging.  Look at the output pane (defaults to "Show output from Build").  If it compiled successfully, the path to the .exe file should be there after {projectname}.vcxproj ->